# Why is the word "hectare" abbreviated as "ha" and not as "he"?

Tags: abbreviations

Why is the word "hectare" abbreviated as "ha" and not as "he"?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hectare

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. *Hectare* is from the Greek *hect*, the multiplier, and *are*, the primary unit of land measurement and the base unit. It means *100 ares*, so it makes sense to abbreviate to the initials of the multiplier and base. We do the same thing with *kilogram* ("kg"; not "ki"), *millimetre* ("mm"; not "mi"), *nanosecond* ("ns"; not "na"), and so on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hectare is from the Greek hect, the multiplier, and are, the primary unit of land measurement and the base unit. It means 100 ares, so it makes sense to abbreviate to the initials of the multiplier and base. We do the same thing with kilogram ("kg"; not "ki"), millimetre ("mm"; not "mi"), nanosecond ("ns"; not "na"), and so on.  – [comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/559369/why-is-the-word-hectare-abbreviated-as-ha-and-not-as-he#comment1380915_559369) by [niamulbengali](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/407392/niamulbengali)

Comment: @Anton - I posted as  “community wiki”. Please check before talking about plagiarism.

Comment: @Anton - it is not my answer!!! It is a community wiki from a comment that should be posted as an answer. I ***am not*** earning rep points on it.

Comment: Comment deleted. Thanks for the explanation. I had not realised that feature of the site previously.